# Foundation Orbit Slides repainting entire page on each transition (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, repaint, orbit

using:

Chrome 36.0.1985.125

Foundation Orbit 5.2.2 with `animation: slide`

I have a slide show, 5 slides, at the top of my page.  They are set to transition via `slide` every 3000 ms.
I first noticed the repaint issue described below due to Fancybox being called near the bottom of the page.  While the Fancybox iframe was "popped out" there would be a quick white flash / flicker affecting everything apart from the iframe, every 3 seconds.
Using Chrome's inspector's Timeline view as well as the Rendering option to "Show paint rectangles" proved my suspicions correct.

**Even when the slide set (the top of the page) is off screen, still every 3 seconds there is a page-wide repaint.  With the inspector's Timeline, I can see a "heartbeat" every 3 seconds in the flow, even when scrolled all the way to the bottom of the page, including a large purple and green spike, where purple represents rendering and green represents painting.  With the Rendering option "Show paint rectangles" I see, again even when scrolled all the way to the bottom of the page, a quick flash of every element on the page framed and tinted in green (being painted) every 3 seconds.**

I've looked around quite a bit for "*foundation orbit flickering*," "*orbit slideshow repaint*" "*foundation orbit repaint offscreen*," and similar terms and have so far not discovered anything of use.

One or two pages I read mentioned a font change or font flicker at regular intervals relating to the slides' transitions.  The "fix" (or workaround) there was to change the `animation` parameter's value from `slide` to `fade`.  Trying this, I found that the repaint issue went away completely.  However, I would prefer to use the `slide` transition.

I haven't been able to reproduce this in Safari or Firefox, but I also don't know what developer tools to use in either of those browsers that would confirm or deny whether the repaint is occurring (i.e. the equivalent of Timeline or "Show paint rectangles" in Chrome's inspector).  Failing that behind-the-scenes proof, it is the case that in Firefox and Safari, with the Fancybox iframe popped out near the bottom of the page, there is no white flash / flicker, as there is in Chrome due to the repaint.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
And yes, I realise that the Foundation Orbit slideshow is no longer supported.
Many thanks.